# How do I escape a comma in korn shell?

Tags: shell, ksh

The following:

```
#!/bin/sh

FOX="{ab,cd}"
echo $FOX
```

outputs what I'd expect ({ab,cd}) but:

```
#!/bin/ksh

FOX="{ab,cd}"
echo $FOX
```

turns the comma into a space. Why is this? I also cannot seem to escape the comma with '\'.

Comment: use dbl quotes on your `echo "$FOX"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting brace expansion when `$FOX` is evaluated.

From the ksh man page:

For the form `{*,*}`:

> a field is created for each string between { and ,, between , and ,, and between , and }.

So the shell is taking your comma separated list and expanding it so that it can be used, for example, in a for loop.

As, shellter suggested in the comments, this can be fixed by double-quoting `"$FOX"` whenever it is evaluated.